# Demo a CLI program without a notebook

Tags: python, linux, scripting, command-line-interface

A client has asked that I put together a Python program to demonstrate some core concepts of a possible ML app. We agreed I would make a CLI for now just to show how it would work and later we would make a web interface.

I wrote up a proposal and he read it and agreed. I'm now 100% done with this project and would like to collection the 2nd 1/2 of the payment.

Originally he said a video of the functionality was fine, now he is saying it's not and he wants to 'play with it'.

I don't want to give him the code, and I really don't want to do any more work for this client until he pays the rest of the money.

**Here's my question:** Is there a way to publish a Python CLI online without:

1. Doing a lot more work (like making a web interface).
2. Exposing the source code.

If he had to SSH into somewhere that might work.

Comment: You could look into [streamlit](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit). It allows you to build a web app from `python` code really quickly. You could deploy it locally and have the client "play with it" via `ngrok`. If you really don't want to put any more effort in it you could perhaps use a dockerized jupyter server.

Comment: How would a dockerized jupyter server help?

Comment: You can deploy it locally, install your module and allow access through SSH or ngrok.